# Split code in bash brace expansion

Tags: bash

I have got stupid question about line break in bash while using brace expansion.

For example, i have got something like this:

```
echo {a,b,c,d}
```

Now i want split code on several lines:

```
echo {a,b, \
     c,d}
```

And it does not works. What is correct and beautiful way to split code on with brace expansion? Thx

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Also what's your goal here?

Comment: I just got a very long line, and want make it more easy readable)

Comment: Is your brace expansion just a list of strings? If so, why use a brace expansion at all? Each string could be on its own line with ``\`` at the end of each line.  Or in an array.

Comment: Yep, it list of strings. It contains a list of files which should be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713684/split-code-in-bash-brace-expansion/713689#comment1351802_713684), the brace expansion is used to store a list of filenames.

This could also be done, and neater, in a shell array:

```bash
files=(
    file1
    file2
    file{A..K}
    some/other/file
    some/directory/*.txt
    'file with spaces in its name'
)
```

Note that the filename glob in the penultimate entry will be expanded to all matching names. Likewise, the third entry will be expanded to `fileA`, `fileB`, ..., `fileK` due to the brace expansion.

Then, loop over the array to copy the files:

```bash
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    cp "$file" some/destination
done
```

or just (if there's less than a few thousand files),

```bash
cp "${files[@]}" some/destination
```

Note that the quoting above is deliberate and important, or you may not be able to support all valid pathnames.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, just remove the space

```
$ echo {a..\
> z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the extra spaces:

```bash
echo X{a,b,\
c,d}Y{e,f\
,g,h}W
```

This↑↑↑ works and produces the expected output:

```
XaYeW XaYfW XaYgW XaYhW XbYeW XbYfW XbYgW XbYhW XcYeW XcYfW XcYgW XcYhW XdYeW XdYfW XdYgW XdYhW
```

However, explicit `for`-cycles may be (sometimes) easier to read (albeit more verbose) than complex multi-line expansions. The same output once again:

```bash
for x in {a..d}; do for y in {e..h}; do array+=("X${x}Y${y}W"); done; done
echo "${array[@]}"
```